# Что такое "все необходимые для работы программы файлы" на Java?

Tags: jar, exe, java, zip

> Присылать нужно zip-архив, содержащий все необходимые для работы программы файлы (исключая JRE, разумеется).

Что же нужно послать. Я понял, что архив с Jar-ником? Или может exe? Что думаете?

Answer (score 2):

jar.
Если исходников не требуют, то посылать исходники не нужно.

А командный файл - это батник, вызывающий компилятор jdk, с кодом вроде
javac helloworld.java
Если исходников *.java нет, очевидно, он не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется исходники + командные файлы для сборки.

Comment: Поясните, что имеет в виду под командными файлами?